# Fix a warning thrown by HTML Validator

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, validation, xhtml

I have some JavaScript code in my php website.
This code uses jQuery, and builds a < select > menu using ajax calls.

Here is the code

```
sel.append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].nombre + '</option>');
```

And this gives me the following warning

***line 240 column 82 - Warning: '<' + '/' + letter not allowed here***

Does anyone know how can I fix this warning, so my html validates? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the character codes?

Comment: Where does the warning came from? The W3C HTML validator?

Comment: @christopher-w-allen-polle: I'll try!
@powtac: Yes, I use the HTML Validator extension in Firefox

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that any `</` sequence — known as ETAGO — ends a CDATA element such as a `<script>`. You can get away with `</` in browsers but not `</script`.

The simplest workaround is to break up the `</` sequence with a backslash-escape:

```
sel.append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].nombre + '<\/option>');
```

However this line still has problems, because you aren't HTML-escaping your `id` and `nombre` values. If they may contain `<`, `&` or `"`, you've just built yourself a client-side XSS vulnerability!

So either HTML-escape your text values before putting them into strings, or, perhaps simpler, just use the standard DOM:

sel.append(new Option(data[i].nombre, data[i].id));

Comment: (Using standard DOM)++. innerHTML is quick and dirty, but mostly dirty.

Comment: Hi bobince, I think your answer is the best choice. I tried the sel.append (new Option...) and worked.

Now my "sub-question" would be, how do you add an option with some attributes? like class="firstoption", an id, etc.?

Hope you've understood me

Comment: You can say `var option= new Option(...)` then treat it as any other DOM element, for example `option.className= 'firstoption';` or jQuery `$(option).addClass('firstoption');`.

Answer (score 4):

Put the javascript in an external file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing javascript in the html/xhtml page, you can enclose the javascript in CDATA

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
console.log("..js code here..");
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: A `</` sequence inside an XML CDATA section is still invalid when served as HTML, which XHTML almost always is. A `</script` sequence inside the CDATA section will still break HTML browsers.

Answer (score 1):

To include code which isn't encoded as XML in an XHTML document (and I'm guessing that's what you're trying to do) you need to do something like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

alert("<This is now valid XHTML>");

//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: This is a tolerable solution for dealing with inline script in XHTML — but the validator would complain about the `<option` instead of the `</`, so the question is about HTML.

Answer (score -2):

Put `<!--` and `-->` around your code.

Comment: That is a hack for Netscape 2.0 era browsers … that won't solve this problem.

Comment: Has no effect against HTML4 (or HTML 3.2!). Breaks script in XML.

Comment: It doesn't work (for the given problem) and browsers ignore the whole script if it is XHTML (unless it is served up at text/html). Argh. I hate XHTML as text/html.

Comment: `<!--...-->` is an XML comment literal in JavaScript 1.6+